# Cannot locate why the cards are not staying within the grid format

Tags: html, css, vue.js, layout, css-grid

I am trying to make a responsive grid, that contains cards, however, I cannot for the life of me figure out why the cards are not not fitting within the columns correctly. When using `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));` The cards end up overflowing the container due to not correctly fitting within the columns. I have also tried `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));` which solved the overflow of the container issue, however, the cards still do not fit into the columns correctly, although they fit better, and I do not want the addition of blank columns when the width of the screen allows it.

The App.vue code:

```
<script setup>
import { RouterView } from "vue-router";
import CardList from "./components/CardList.vue";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar.vue";
</script>

<template>
  <div class="container">
    <NavBar />
    <CardList />
    <main class="main-body">
      <RouterView />
    </main>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

main > .main-body {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
</style>
```

The CardList code:

```
<template>
  <div class="cards-container">
    <HoverLogo
      v-for="item in items"
      class="card-container"
      :key="item"
      :title="item.title"
      :points="item.points"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Card from "./Card.vue";

export default {
  name: "CardList",
  components: { Card },
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          title: "Annual Leave",
          points: [
            "9 days left to take",
            "4 sick days taken",
            "8 days of upcoming annual leave",
          ],
        },
        {
          title: "Benefits",
          points: ["Gym memberhip", "Health Insurance", "Wellbeing centre"],
        },
        {
          title: "Payroll",
          points: ["Payslips", "Tax", "Contact Payroll"],
        },
        {
          title: "Pension",
          points: ["Pension paid so far", "Change Pension Contribution"],
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.cards-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#141e30, #243b55);
  column-gap: 100px;
}

.cards-container:hover .card {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .cards-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
</style>
```

The Card code:

```
<template>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="dark">
        <div class="face face1">
          <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="face face2">
          <div class="content">
            <p v-for="point in points" :key="point" class="points">
              {{ point }}
            </p>
            <button @click="signUp">
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              Read More
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Card",
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    points: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: arial;
}
.body > .container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.dark:hover .face {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.dark:hover .face h3 {
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #03e9f4, 0 0 25px #03e9f4, 0 0 50px #03e9f4,
    0 0 100px #03e9f4;
}
.face {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: 0.7s;
}
.face1 {
  font-family: Blanka;
  color: #03e9f4;
  position: relative;
  background: #0d1520;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(100px);
}

.face1 > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.face.face1 .content {
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
}
.face.face1 .content .h3 {
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
.face.face1 .content .a {
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.face.face2 {
  position: relative;
  background: whitesmoke;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: translateY(-100px);
}
.face2 button {
  background: #0d1520;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #03e9f4;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin-top: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border: none;
}

.face2 > .content > .points {
  color: #0d1520;
  font-family: Blanka;
}

.face2 button:hover {
  background: #03e9f4;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #03e9f4, 0 0 10px #03e9f4, 0 0 20px #03e9f4,
    0 0 100px #03e9f4;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.face2 button span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

.face2 button span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim1 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes btn-anim1 {
  0% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

.face2 button span:nth-child(2) {
  top: -100%;
  right: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim2 2s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes btn-anim2 {
  0% {
    top: -100%;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    top: 100%;
  }
}

.face2 button span:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 0;
  right: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim3 2s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes btn-anim3 {
  0% {
    right: -100%;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    right: 100%;
  }
}

.face2 button span:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(360deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim4 2s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes btn-anim4 {
  0% {
    bottom: -100%;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    bottom: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
```

A picture showing the issue with auto-fit:
[image]

**Edit:**

[Code Pen Link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: It would help us a lot if you could make an online reproduction on [sfc.vuejs.org](https://sfc.vuejs.org/) or codepen 

Comment: @Kapcash, I've added a codepen

Comment: the `face` class has hardcoded `width: 300px;` which your grid layout cannot physically fit which causes the overflow.  the grid cannot override hardcoded widths so if you remove that width you'll suddenly find your content fitting inside their columns much better

Comment: @yoduh, thank you for the help, I have solved the problem based off your response below :)

Answer (score 0):

Based off @yoduh 's comment, I figured out the issue. Because of the fixed width of 300px on the Card.vue:

```
.face {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: 0.7s;
}
```

combined with the minimum of 200px minmax on the Card-List.vue:

```
.cards-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#141e30, #243b55);
  column-gap: 100px;
  min-height: 95vh;
}
```

It was causing issues, I therefore changed the minimum on the minmax to 300px and that fixed the issue.